# How to fix the error I am getting when running py2app (py to .exe)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, exe, py2app

These are all of the libraries I use in my project:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTabBar, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QToolBar, QToolButton, QMenu, QLineEdit, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QTabWidget, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QStyle, QAbstractItemView, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QLabel, QDesktopWidget, QStylePainter, QStyleOptionButton, QInputDialog, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence, QFont, QIcon, QFontMetrics, QTextCursor, QPainter, QColor, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QRect, pyqtSignal, QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSocketNotifier, QSize
from PyQt5 import QtSvg
from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla, QsciLexerPython, QsciLexerCSS, QsciLexerHTML, QsciLexerJavaScript, QsciLexerCustom, QsciAPIs
import PyQt5
from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import RichJupyterWidget
from qtconsole.manager import QtKernelManager
from pathlib import Path
from pylint import lint
from pylint.reporters.text import TextReporter
import os
import re
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt5'
import subprocess
import sys
import shutil
import pickle
import threading
import webbrowser
import locale, pty, struct, termios
from datetime import datetime
```

and for some reason I am receiving this error in my project containing qt6 even though it is not even associated with my project. In general though I do not fully understand this error:

```
  setup(


 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 932, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1162, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1259, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1108, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/recipes/qt6.py", line 20, in check
    from PyQt6.QtCore import QLibraryInfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6.QtCore'
```

This is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    app=["Yuro.py"],
setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Comment: read the last 3 lines of the error.  it means QLibraryInfo.location function not found

Comment: How do I fix this error, I looked everywhere online to try to solve it.

Comment: try importing it the way you did and then run dir on QLibraryInfo - not everything in c++ qt turned verbatim to python stuff.

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky 1. Improve your imports (don't use `*`). 2. Use a virtualenv, not the system python, to limit the problems caused by packages, 2. If you have PyQt6 or PySide6 installed then uninstall it as py2app seems to try to use it causing that problem.

Comment: I do not have PyQt6 or PySide6 installed and I will reedit my imports right now.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited and still get the error above, I do not have PyQt6 and PySide6 installed.